# While entering a string in an single element of array in c why does the following code gives the shown output?

Tags: c, c99

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n, m;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    char s[m][n];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("the string --\n");
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("the strings are %s \n",s[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2 2  
the string --
10  
the string -- 
11  

the strings are 1011 

the strings are 11
```

Why is the first string `1011` instead of `10`?

Comment: Your `n` dimension needs to be 3, not 2.  To store an N-character string, you need an array with *at least* N+1 elements to account for the 0 terminator.

Comment: To have a C-"string" store N characters define it to be of size N+1. Mind its `0`-terminator.

Comment: `char s[m][n];` --> `char s[m][n+1];`

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are represented as a sequence of `char` values, terminated by a null character (`0` or `'\0'`). This means that to store a two-character string, you need space for three characters: the two characters of string content, plus the null terminator character.

Here, you've only allocated enough space for two characters in each string, but you need space for three.

So, it reads the first string into the array `s[0]`, but the null terminator doesn't fit, and so it overflows into the second array `s[1]`. Now your array of arrays `s` looks like this: `{{'1', '0'}, {'\0', ... }}`.

Then, when it reads the second string into the array `s[1]`, it overwrites the overflowed null terminator from before. And the null terminator for the second string doesn't fit into its own array, so it overflows again into the rest of the stack. The program might crash here, or corrupt other data, because you're overflowing past the end of the array.

So now your array of arrays `s` ends up looking like this: `{{'1', '0'}, {'1', '1'}}`, followed by a `'\0'` somewhere after the end of the array.

When `printf` goes to read your first string, it prints characters until it finds a null terminator. But it doesn't find one in the first string, so it keeps going, and hits the second string. It doesn't find one there either, and continues past the end of the array. In your case, luckily a null terminator was right there, but for all we know there could be something else.

To fix this, you need to allocate an extra character per string on line 9, for the null terminator:

```
    char s[m][n+1];
```

---

There's another problem here, however. What if your input gives you the wrong length? For example, what if your input says `2 3`, i.e. that the following strings will have a length of 3, but gives you the string `foobar`, which is *6* characters? Your code right now would overflow the buffer when it read that string, because it doesn't ensure it's the right length.

One way to avoid this would be to use `gets_s` instead of `sscanf()` for reading the strings on line 13:

```
        gets_s(s[i], n+1);
```

This will read at most `n` characters, so avoid crashing your program or creating a security issue. However, `gets_s` is a C11 function, so you may not be able to use it.

Comment: That's the first part of the issue, OP also need to read (or copy into the array) **only** n chars (plus the null) for every row.

Comment: Well, you should always assume the input may be malformed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must set column size to 3 if you insert 2 characters per string, 4 for 3 characters per string and so on.
This because string in C have a termination character `('\0')` in the last position.

Answer (score 0):

```
     #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n, m;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    char s[m][n+1];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("the string --\n");
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("the strings are %s \n",s[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try this code,,you must maintain the size of length n of a string...n will greater than the numbers of digit of number.

Answer (score -1):

`%s` expects null terminated strings as an argument. When first string is read by `scanf`, there is not enough space for the null terminator within the allocated memory of first string. It will goes to the space next to the allocated space. Writing to unallocated space invokes undefined behavior.

While printing the strings with `%s` specifier, `printf` write the string character by character till it finds a null terminator `'\0'`. Here it may be the case that both the strings `10` and `11` are stored one after another in memory, so printf writes the first string till it read the null character of second string.
Input `n` as `3` and you will get the desire results.

Comment: Why aren't his strings null-terminated? `scanf()` writes null-terminated strings into the variable.

Comment: There is no space for `'\0'` in variables here. It may be the case that `scanf` write `'\0'`after the first string but that character is overwritten by the first character of the second string.

Comment: It still tries to write it, causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

In my opninion using scanf to read strings is just pure evil.
That said the array `s[m][n]` is just `s[m*n]` of course.
That said that evil thing `scanf` is going to load on `*s[0] 10\n\0` and on `*s[1*n]` or `*s[2] 11` and `*s` will be `1011\n\0`

And this is a monument to bad C coding. I guess it's just an example but if I was asked this question i would say: "Come on, get me real things"